# Ctrl+C to break an infinite loop and then do something outside the loop in a bash script without exiting?

Tags: linux, bash, infinite-loop, sigint

I have read so many answers and they all just suggest to kill the script or send it to the background etc. What I want is

while true
do

something...

if(ctrl+c is pressed break)

done
echo "Out of the loop"

I am outside the loop because ctrl+c was pressed and so I can do other stuffs here without exiting the script....

And this question is not a duplicate because I have searched for hours and no answer gives me what I want. That "Out of the loop" never gets printed, I tried so many examples from various answers !

Info: I use (1) Scientific Linux SL release 5.4 (Boron),  (2) Ubuntu 16.04

**Edit: I want this exact code to work**

```
#!/bin/bash

loopN=0

while true
do

echo "Loop Number = $i"
i=$(($i+1))

#I want to break this loop when Ctrl+C is pressed

done

#Ctrl+C has been pressed so I am outside the loop going to do something..

echo "Exited the loop, there were $i number of loopsexecuted !"
#here I will execute some commands.. let's say date
date

#and then I will exit the script
```

Comment: You want to **trap** ''Ctrl-C'' Here are some examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771909/bash-using-trap-ctrlc If you want more specific help show us what you tried (actual code)

Comment: @Nifle I have included an example, how can I make that specific example work ?

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash

#function called by trap
do_this_on_ctrl_c(){
    echo "Exited the loop, there were $i number of loops executed !"
    date
    exit 0
}

trap 'do_this_on_ctrl_c' SIGINT

loopN=0

while true
do
    echo "Loop Number = $i"
    i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot. I have noticed that this works when I execute it using `./script.sh` but it fails if I `source script.sh` it. I am really new to this scripting business but I would very much like to learn.

Comment: strange problem again ! It works on Scientific Linux (SL release 5.4 boron) but on Ubuntu 16.04, `Ctrl + C` takes me out of the script before even calling  the function `do_this_on_ctrl_c()` at all. What should I do to make it work on my Ubuntu ?